# HTTP 400 Bad Request response while testing Thomson Reuters World Check One API

Tags: apex, integration, httprequest

I tried to see the request header values before it is send to external webserver. But Httprequest.getbody() methods returns empty. I tried this code below. Also, I have tried to convert the java code which has been given as an example for the POST request. Please see the java code also given below the apex code.

```
public with sharing class testingscenario
{
    public static String generateAuthHeader(String dataToSign)
    {
        String algorithmName = 'HmacSHA256';
        Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(dataToSign), Blob.valueOf('**********************************'));
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
    }
    @Future(callout = true)
    public static void getvalues(String JsonString)
    {

        try {
        String gatewayurl = '/v1/';
        String gatewayhost = 'somewebsite.com';
        String apikey = '**************************';
        String apisecret = '**************************************';

        String contentType = 'application/json';
        String ND=Datetime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');

        //String jsonBody =  '{\"secondaryFields\":[],\"entityType\":\"INDIVIDUAL\",\"customFields\":[],\"groupId\":\"418f28a7-b9c9-4ae4-8530-819c61b1ca6c\",\"providerTypes\":[\"WATCHLIST\"],\"name\":\"george w bush\"}';
          String jsonBody =  '{ \"secondaryFields\": [], \"entityType": \"INDIVIDUAL\", \"customFields\": [], "groupId\":\"*********************\", \"providerTypes\": [ \"WATCHLIST\" ], \"name\": \"putin\" }';        

        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

        List<String> str1 = new List<String>();
        List<String> str2 = new List<String>();
        str2.add('WATCHLIST');


        // Write data to the JSON string.
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField('secondaryFields', str1);
        gen.writeStringField('entityType', 'INDIVIDUAL');
        gen.writeObjectField('customFields',str1);
        gen.writeStringField('groupId', '***********************');
        gen.writeObjectField('ProviderTypes', str2);
        gen.writeStringField('name', 'george');

        gen.writeEndObject();

        // Get the JSON string.
        String pretty = gen.getAsString();
        System.debug('json string:>>>>>>>>>'+pretty );
        System.debug('json body:>>>>>>>>>'+jsonbody);
        String content = JSON.serialize(jsonbody);
        Integer Contentlength=192; //pretty.length();
        System.debug('Contentlengthhhhhh'+Contentlength);


/*
        String dataToSign = '(request-target): post' + gatewayurl+ 'cases\n' + 
                'host: ' + gatewayhost + '\n' +
                'date: ' + ND +'\n'+ 
                'content-type: '+contentType +'\n' + 
                'content-length: '+ Contentlength + '\n' + 
                content;
*/      

        String dataToSign2 = '(request-target): post ' + gatewayurl + 'cases\n' +
        'host: ' + gatewayhost  + '\n' +
        'date: ' + ND + '\n' +
        'content-type: ' + contentType  +'\n' + 
        'content-length: ' + contentLength + '\n' + 
        content;                

        String dataToSign1 = '(request-target): post /v1/cases host: somewebsite.com date: Fri, 22 Sep 2017 22:13:50 GMT content-type: application/json content-length: 192 { \"secondaryFields\": [], \"entityType\": \"INDIVIDUAL\", \"customFields\": [], \"groupId\":\"************************\", \"providerTypes\": [ \"WATCHLIST\" ], \"name\": \"putin\" }';

        String hmac = generateAuthHeader(dataToSign1);

        String authorisation = 'Signature keyId=\"' + apikey + '\",algorithm=\"hmac-sha256\",headers=\"(request-target) host date content-type content-length\",signature=\"' + hmac + '\"';
        //String authorisation = 'Signature keyId=\"**********************\",algorithm=\"hmac-sha256\",headers=\"(request-target) host date content-type content-length\",signature=\"***********************"';

        System.debug('authorisation Result'+authorisation);
        System.debug('dataToSign Result'+dataToSign1 );
        System.debug('hmac Result'+hmac);




        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        request.setEndpoint('https://somewebsite.com/v1/cases');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setTimeout(120000);
        request.setHeader('Authorization',authorisation);
        request.setHeader('Date',ND);
        request.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type',  'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(contentlength));

        System.debug('request body>>>>>>'+request.getBody());
        System.debug('request body Document>>>>>>'+request.getBodyDocument());

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(request);
        System.debug('response>>>>>>'+res);
        } catch(exception ex) {
            system.debug(ex.getmessage());
        }



    }
}
```

**Java Code for POST Request:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
//import org.apache.commons.logging.*;
import org.json.*;

public class PostRequest {

    public static String generateAuthHeader(String dataToSign, String secret)
   {      
    String hash = "";
      try { 

          Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
          SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
          sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
          hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(dataToSign.getBytes()));
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error");
      }
        return(hash);
   }




       // A simple request to create a Case using Http Post
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            try {
                Date now = new Date();

                //format for date string Mon, 27 Mar 2017 15:19:36 GMT 
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
                df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

                String date = df.format(now);
                String gatewayurl = "/v1/";
                String gatewayhost = "someapiwebsite.com";
                String apikey = "**************************************";
                String apisecret = "**************************************";
                String groupid = "**************************************";

                //create a JSON string 
                String jsonBody =  "{\"secondaryFields\":[],\"entityType\":\"INDIVIDUAL\",\"customFields\":[],\"groupId\":\"**************************************\",\"providerTypes\":[\"WATCHLIST\"],\"name\":\"george w bush\"}";

                // create a JSON object from the JSON string
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonBody);

                //System.out.println(jo.toString());

                String jlen = String.valueOf(jo.toString().length());
                String dataToSign = "(request-target): post " + gatewayurl + "cases\n" +
                        "host: " + gatewayhost + "\n" +
                        "date: " + date + "\n" +
                        "content-type: " +  "application/json" +"\n" + 
                        "content-length: " + jlen + "\n" + 
                        jo;

                String hmac = generateAuthHeader(dataToSign, apisecret);
                String authorisation = "Signature keyId=\"" + apikey  + "\",algorithm=\"hmac-sha256\",headers=\"(request-target) host date content-type content-length\",signature=\"" + hmac + "\"";

                System.out.println(jlen);
                System.out.println(dataToSign);
                //System.out.println(hmac);
                System.out.println(authorisation);
                String msg = jo.toString();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://someapiwebsite.com/v1/cases");

                HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(msg);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);

                httpPost.addHeader("Date", date);
                httpPost.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");         
                httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type",  "application/json" );
                httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", authorisation);        

                // send the POST request
                CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                try {

                    HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
                    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());

                    String json = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
                    //System.out.println(entity1);
                    // json string returned
                    System.out.println(json);
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

                    // printout in Pretty format
                    Object jsonObj = mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
                    String indented = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonObj);
                    System.out.println(indented);

                    EntityUtils.consume(entity1);

                } 
                finally {
                    response1.close();
                }


            } finally {
                httpclient.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66286/discussion-on-question-by-bforce-http-400-bad-request-response-while-testing-tho).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't control the target website and can't access logs there - you could try sending the request to a debug logging endpoint. I tend to do it when I'm building new SOAP / REST integrations. When I hit a problem, I debug log the resulting request Salesforce has produced, load it up in [soapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) / [Chrome REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and keep hacking at the generated message until I get something meaningful from the target system...

If you don't have your own "request sink" that would log anything you want, you can use https://requestb.in/ It's very simple to use and for your code it means only 2 things:

- adding requestb.in to Remote Site Settings
- commenting out the original `request.setEndpoint()`

As to what's actually wrong - can be anything. Maybe your content-type header is not something the target application expects. Maybe the message signing algorithm is not implemented the way they expect. That's why it's a good idea to send your stuff to such "request sink" and when all else fails - contact target app's developer for assistance, showing him/her the raw output produced by SF.

(No, I'm not affiliated with request bin, soapUI and any other tool like that)

---

**Edit**

Here's a working Salesforce implementation of [Thomson Reuter's World-Check One API](https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/customer-and-third-party-screening/world-check-one-api) based on their sample Java program.

```java
public with sharing class Stack193260 {

    static final String gatewayurl = '/v1/';
    static final String gatewayhost = 'rms-world-check-one-api-pilot.thomsonreuters.com';
    static final String endpoint = 'https://rms-world-check-one-api-pilot.thomsonreuters.com/v1/cases';
    static final String apiKey = '(redacted)';
    static final String apiSecret = '(redacted)';

    static String sign(String payload){
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(payload), Blob.valueOf(apiSecret)));
    }

    public static void sendCase(){
        Payload p = new Payload();

        String formattedTimestamp = Datetime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
        String contentType = 'application/json';
        String content = JSON.serialize(p);
        String contentLength = String.valueOf(content.length());

        String dataToSign = String.join(new List<String>{
            '(request-target): post ' + gatewayurl + 'cases',
            'host: ' + gatewayhost,
            'date: ' + formattedTimestamp,
            'content-type: ' + contentType,
            'content-length: '+ contentLength,
            content
        }, '\n');
        System.debug(dataToSign);

        String signature = sign(dataToSign);
        System.debug(signature);

        String authorisation = 'Signature keyId="' + apiKey + '",algorithm="hmac-sha256",headers="(request-target) host date content-type content-length",signature="' + signature + '"';
        System.debug(authorisation);


        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization',authorisation);
        req.setHeader('Date',formattedTimestamp);
        req.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type',  contentType);
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', contentLength);
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(content);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
    }

    public class Payload {
        public List<String> secondaryFields;
        public String entityType;
        public List<String> customFields;
        public String groupId;
        public List<String> providerTypes;
        public String name;

        //  Bit stupid constructor, provides sample values. Ideally you'd pass to it a Case record or whatever?
        public Payload(){
            secondaryFields = new List<String>();
            entityType = 'INDIVIDUAL';
            customFields = new List<String>();
            groupId = '418f28a7-b9c9-4ae4-8530-819c61b1ca6c';
            providerTypes = new List<String>{'WATCHLIST'};
            name = 'george w bush';
        }
    }
}
```

You need to provide your own API keys. Successful request will receive a response with HTTP 201 "Created" and JSON payload starting with something like

```
{"caseId":"a266ba18-7b63-414b-a0bc-907dd4676970","name":"george w bush" ...
```